# Jasmine: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am having a function which checks if name exists in an array (names_array). If exists return true else if not then push the name to names_array and create table rows for each name and append to table.

Using Jasmine I have to test if the function is returning true or false.
For this I am passing values for variables names_array and name.
But still getting undefined variable error for the code $('#add_name').val();

My javascript code to test is...

```
function check_names(names_array) {
    var name = $('#add_name').val().toLowerCase();
    //check if name is there in names_array if yes return true, if not then return false and push the item to the names_array
    }
```

Jasmine code which I am using..

```
describe("On Name Create",function (){
var names_array = ["add","bad","sad","dad"];
   it("Check for names",function (){
        var name = "add";
        expect(check_names(names_array)).toBeTruthy();
   });
 });
```

Am I missing something as I am new to Jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that $(‘#add_name).val() is not null.

Also maybe you should try $(‘#add_name).eq(0).val()

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I understand that the error is because of $('#add_name').val() which it is not able to fetch. I using Jasmine for unit testing.. and I don't know how to mock the value for $('#add_name').val() ..  I tried var name = "add"; but its not working..

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because `$('#add_name').val()` not providing any value to `toLowerCase()` function.

Make sure `#add_name`, this id in your HTML code have some value with it. You can print it before it's use in your code.